# Add string array to combobox c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, xaml, combobox

I need to add 12 strings to a ComboBox in WPF application. Using XAML is very hard because I have to add one by one. So I used string array to do so.

I used the following code,

```
string[] arrayMonth = new string[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",  
    "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

cmbMonth_Finance_ES.ItemsSource = arrayMonth;
```

But ComboBox loads empty. I tried all over the internet but found nothing. So please help me to add string array into a ComboBox.

Comment: it should work.. can you share the whole method where you are filling combo and xaml where combo is

Comment: else if (tabControlMain.SelectedIndex == 5 && e.Key == Key.D3)           {
   tabControlFinance.SelectedIndex = 2;

 string[] arrayMonth = new string[] { "January",  "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

  cmbMonth_Finance_ES.ItemsSource = arrayMonth;
                
 }

Comment: does your breakpoint hit inside this elseif block? cmbMonth_Finance_ES is not your locally created combo rt?

Comment: can you Update question with your xaml code and related code behind code?